# Login redireciona para o action ao invés do header

Tags: php, login, header

Olá, estou fazendo uma página de login porém ela não está redirecionando da forma que eu gostaria, utilizando o header, ao invés disso quando eu clico em entrar ele vai pra action do formulário.
O arquivo dando problema é este aqui(postlogin.php):

```
<?php

    session_start();
    

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    
    if(strlen($email) > 0 && strlen($senha) > 0) {
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "projeto_morada");
    
    
    //Execução da instrução sql
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * from usuario where email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha';");
    
    
    //$usuarios recebe a lista de usuários 
    
    $usuarios = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
    
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $usuarios[0][1];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $usuarios[0][2];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $usuarios[0][3];
    
    header('Location: http://localhost/projeto_morada/index.php');
    }
    else {
    
    echo "
    
    <script>
    alert('E-mail ou senha inválidos!')
    location.href = 'index.php'
    </script>
    ";
    
    }
};
    ?>
```

E o formulário está assim:

```
          <form class="form" method="post" action="postlogin.php">

                    <label class="label-input" for="email">
                        <i class="far fa-envelope icon-modify"></i>
                        <input type="email"  id="email" onkeyup="valida_login()" placeholder="E-mail">
                    </label>

                    <label class="label-input" for="senha">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock icon-modify"></i>
                        <input type="password" id="senha" onkeyup="valida_login()" placeholder="Senha">
                    </label>

                    <a class="password" href="#">Esqueceu sua senha?
                    </a>
                    <button class="btn btn-second" id="login">entre</button>
```

Comment: No caso o primeiro arquivo seria o `postlogin.php`, correto?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema esta no formulário, as tags inputs estão sem o atributo `name`, adicione nas tags input o atributo `name` para que o php possa receber na `action`
exemplo:
Input email
`<input type="email"  id="email" onkeyup="valida_login()" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">`
Input senha
`<input type="password" id="senha" onkeyup="valida_login()" placeholder="Senha" name="senha">`

Comment: putz, era isso mesmo muitíssimo obrigada!!

Comment: kkjj as vezes um detalhe muito simplés acaba causando grandes confusões. 
 Coloca a resposta como certa.